# deserialize object with a factory method

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have an object that has an array of objects that are created with a factory method.  Serialization is working fine, I can see all of the properties on the objects, but when deserializing, the properties on the array of objects are not being set.

How can I use the factory method used to create these objects when the document deserializes back to it's original object structure?

I've tried using a MapCreator like this:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Attribute>(cm =>
            {
                cm.AutoMap();
                cm.MapCreator(a => Attribute.Create(a.Name, a.GetValue(), a.IsVisible, a.GroupName, a.Priority));
            });
```

But I get the following exception:

[MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException] = {"The only operations allowed on the prototype parameter are accessing a field or property."}

If I need to create a custom serializer, I'm not sure how to deserialize the array of objects, how to iterate through the array data in the bson reader.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a.GetValue(). Each parameter has to map back to a property or field in your class and GetValue() doesn't. Name, IsVisible, GroupName, and Priority are all mappable, but not GetValue() because it's a method. Remember that this is you telling us on how to construct your Attribute class. We can use the properties because we know how they've been mapped. But it isn't possible to map a method in the current version of the driver. If you'd like to file a feature request for mapping methods, you can do that at jira.mongodb.org under the CSHARP project.

Craig